# Passing callback function to a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, parameter-passing

I am creating a jQuery plugin that accepts input options, as described in [this link](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#accepting-options). The following is the same code from the above link

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white"
        }, options );

        // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
        return this.css({
            color: settings.color,
            backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

I am also extending the plugin a little bit, so that it will trigger a user function if the user passes a callback function. So, the plugin evolved to the following:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white",

            onGreenify: function () {} // This is a new option
        }, options );

        // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
        var newCss = this.css({
            color: settings.color,
            backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
        });

        // Execute the function
        if (typeof settings.onGreenify == "function") {
            settings.onGreenify ();
        }

        return newCss;
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

And when the user does this:

```
var greenifyOptions = {
    onGreenify: function () {
        console.log("Element is now green.");
    }
}

$("#id1").greenify(greenifyOptions);
```

then the above bit of code will run successfully and display the message **Element is now green.** to the console.

So far so good.

Now, here is the problem I am facing. How can I pass input param(s) to the `onGreenify` function? For example, I would like to do the following:

```
var name = "John";
var greenifyOptions = {
    onGreenify: function (name) {
        console.log ("Hello " + name +  ". Element is now green.");
    }
}

$("#id1").greenify(greenifyOptions);
```

which should eventually display **Hello John. Element is now green.** to the console.

But I am not sure how to modify the following code to allow it to accept input param(s)

```
if (typeof settings.onGreenify == "function") {
    settings.onGreenify ();
}
```

Please note, this function should accept any number of input parameters. I do not have control over what the user needs to pass.

Is my approach right? What is the piece of code that needs to be modified?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are the parameters supposed to come from? How is that plugin supposed to know that it should pass parameters or what their values should be?

Comment: the name passed must be from the pluging scope, not global scope, review this concept to think about you need, anyway i put  a demo, because i'd like the concept i belive you try to make

Comment: @Pointy - What do you mean exactly? Those params are pointed out in the example I provided

Comment: Think about how function calls work. The calling environment has to have some awareness of what it's supposed to pass to the function. Your function is written to expect a string (`name`) to be passed. Some other function might expect a list of numbers.

Comment: @Pointy - This is exactly my question. How do I do that?

Comment: I think what you're *really* looking for is answered by the existence of *closures* in JavaScript. When the options object is constructed, a function can be instantiated that has access to all of the variables in its lexical scope. When the plugin calls it, that function can still access that stuff, without the plugin having to know anything about it. In your example, in fact, `name` doesn't have to be a parameter because that `console.log()` call will already be  able to access that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi here is a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zrz9t/3904/), but there is something bad in your idea, if the name is globale, no need to be passed get directly.. I'm thinking how could be done wit passing a name by element, being something scoped by de pluging
:

```
     (function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {

        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white",

            onGreenify: function () {} // This is a new option

        }, options );

        // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
        var newCss = this.css({
            color: settings.color,
            backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
        });

        // Execute the function
        if (typeof settings.onGreenify == "function") {

            //settings.onGreenify ();
            settings.onGreenify.call(this, settings.name);
        }

        return newCss;

    };

}( jQuery ));
var name = 'juan'
var greenifyOptions = {
        name: 'juaanddd',
    onGreenify: function (name) {
        console.log("Element is "+name+" now green.");
    }
}

$("#id1").greenify(greenifyOptions);
```

Comment: i made an update of this response, giving a custom name for custom object or set of objects

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to do that without passing the input parameter as part of the options (i.e., without the `name` option in `greenifyOptions`. I want the user to pass the function and its input parameters are part of the function itself, as follows `onGreenify: function (name) ( // code here )`

Comment: @Greeso and wherer is name defined?, need to be defined in anywhere